# iOS CoreMotion Gryoscope Update Interval

Tags: ios, core-motion

I am writing an application that uses the Gryoscope in iOS-compatible devices. I only want the gyroscope to update my application with new Coordinates about every second. I've tried to set:

```
motionManager.gryoUpdateInterval=1
```

However, it seems that I'm getting a million updates a second (yes, I know that's hyperbole).

Are there any other settings I need to make, or is this not possible? What is the maximum value for this setting for each device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0; should work.**

But beware that the gyroscope is only on the fourth-generation iPod touch, iPhone 4, and iPad. Try add an if-else statement block to ensure device compatibility.

If you wan't more info try this [link.](http://fromideatoapp.com/bonus-material/)

Comment: Let me try the "1.0", not just "1"